# reciveing 2 records from a hasOne relation laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

this is my model where i set my relation

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Client','id','client_id');
}
```

and here the controller 
i have two relations here my invoice product realtion works fine and well but $clients shows 2 rows in view

```
$clients = Invoice::with('user')->get();
$invoice_id = $invoice->id;
$invoices = Invoice::with('products')->where('id', '=', $invoice_id)->firstOrFail();
return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice','invoices'),compact('clients'));
```

and the view

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
   <td>{{ $client->user->title ?? 'بدون مشتری' }}</td>
@endforeach
```

now when i visit my view i get 2 td tags with the same value of the client name (title) any idea what i have done wrong ?
and here is the dd of the

```
#observables: []


#relations: array:1 [▼
    "user" => Client {#769 ▼
      #fillable: array:14 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:17 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "مشتری اول"
        "description" => "مشتری اول"
        "fax" => 123
        "adrress1" => "مشتری اول"
        "adrress2" => null
        "adrress3" => null
        "adrress4" => null
        "adrress5" => null
        "telephone1" => 123
        "telephone2" => null
        "telephone3" => null
        "telephone4" => null
        "telephone5" => null
        "client_type" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
```

Comment: For all invoice you are getting two user relation as you use get() ?

Comment: are there by chance 2 clients?

Comment: no checked that just 1 client is printing 2 times

Comment: change relation hasOne  to belongsTo   (   return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');   )

Comment: You're calling `->get()` on the `Invoice` model, then looping over them and printing `$invoice->user->title;`. I think you have two invoices, each with the same User. Maybe you should try getting your clients in a different manner, such as `$clients = User::has("invoices")->get();` which will only return clients that have an invoice.

Comment: @TimLewis thats right but i dont have the User model . and if i write this $clients = Invoice::has("user")->get(); i still get the same error just to mention as many invoices as i add to system it shows them all there :)

Comment: Ok, well you have to adjust the code to what you **do** have... `User` should be `Client`, so `$clients = Client::has("invoices")->get();` Just make sure the `invoices` relationship is defined on your `Client` model.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was i was looping through all the relations that would possibly happen for that model so i just did a simple filter which was a were clause for my relation and the set the id of invoice for that to bring just the attributes i need and that more efficient as i see in the documentation

```
        $clients = Invoice::with('user')->where('id','=',$invoice_id)->get();
```